# Game Audio Course Work

Tags: university, game, course

If you were to enroll on a non-degree path in a regular state college, what program would benefit learning more about game audio scripting and implementation? This wouldnt be a tech school or vocation, but a university with no actual game audio courses.

My first thought would be Computer Science. But you probably could narrow it down a bit more couldnt you? Are there C+ (or other related language) courses that would support the basics of game audio scripting?

Your thoughts please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the bigger games are coded in C++, with a healthy dose of scripting thrown in (python, lua, etc).  Iphone uses Objective C and android likes Java.

I am a game sound guy with a CS background and I think it has helped me immensely.  I'd say go for C++.  BTW good audio programmers are RARE and can find jobs relatively easily.

Comment: Thanks David - you have pointed many people in a good direction! Ill look into some local course work. You only pay by the course hour in a non-degree path, so its pretty cheap to get in a good lecture series.

Answer (score 0):

What is audio programming?

Comment: Why is audio programming?